# oracles implementation with smart contracts

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am trying to deploy a smart contract to a private Blockchain which uses oraclizeAPI.sol library code.
Basically the smart contract is a small implementation of oraclize.

The import does not work, either with the github link or with local import, solc compilation fails because of import.

Both of the below does not work, the contract is not getting properly compiled by solc

```
1.import "oraclizeAPI.sol";

2.import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI.sol";
```

So, next approch i took was to copy the code of oraclizeAPI.sol, directly into the contract code file.
Now the contract gets compiled properly but the i am falling shot on gas every time, while deploying.

Error:

```
The contract couldn't be stored, please check your gas amount.
```

Now here are the details of the Blockchain.

genesis.json

```
  {
        "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
        "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "difficulty": "0x4000",
        "alloc": {
            "84840c340067c75806273d2524dfbae646a7c68f": 
            { "balance": "1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376" }
        },
            "config": {
            "chainId": 15,
            "homesteadBlock": 0,
            "eip155Block": 0,
            "eip158Block": 0
        },
        "coinbase": "0x84840c340067c75806273d2524dfbae646a7c68f",
        "timestamp": "0x00",
        "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "gasLimit": "0x8000000000000000"
    }
```

I am currently trying to deply the contract using the coinbase id.

```
web3.eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit
132661998547049420

web3.eth.getBalance('0x84840c340067c75806273d2524dfbae646a7c68f').e
60
```

contract code:

```
contract oraclizeExample is usingOraclize {

    string public data;

    event newOraclizeQuery(string description);
    event newData(string data);
    event eventC(string data);

    function oraclizeExample() payable {
        update();
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
        if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
        data = result;
        newData(result);
        //return result;
    }

    function eventCheck(string dataFClient) returns (string) {
        eventC(dataFClient);
        return dataFClient;
    }

    function update() payable returns (string) {
        newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
        oraclize_query("URL", "json(https://jewel-api.herokuapp.com/jewel/58d89d264d59a000110829bb).invoice_num");
        return "update function was called!";
    }

}
```

The code of contract creation.

```
var ContractABI = web3.eth.contract(JSON.parse(interface));
var SaveContract = ContractABI.new(
    {
        from: account,
        data: bytecode,
        gas: '93048696279858031'
    }, function (e, contract) {
        if(e){
            console.log(e, contract);
            return;
        }

        if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
            console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
            fs.writeFileSync('./contracts_data/'+ contract_name + '_final', 'Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash)
            return; 
        }

    });
```

If you want to check the complete contract code with the and the way i am doing this please got to this link.

https://github.com/utkarsh17ife/oraclizeExample/tree/master/contracts_data

Or the complete implementation with node as well:

https://github.com/utkarsh17ife/oraclizeExample

And yes i am able to mine other contract using this setup.

Comment if you need further info on this.

Comment: You might have more luck on a stackexchange for crypto or maybe even dedicated to Ethereum

Comment: if you want me to try with more ether let me know how much 'balance' shall i put in genesis.json file  & and how much shall i keep the value of  'gas:' in contract creation.

Comment: Ask this question at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a private chain you must run the [ethereum-bridge](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge), you are getting a throw because your smart contract invokes the oraclize_query function on deployment (constructor function) but no Oraclize contracts were found on your chain.